# Finding the probability of a variable in collection of lists

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability

I have a selection of lists of variables

```
import numpy.random as npr 

w = [0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.13, 0.17]

x = 1

y = False

z = [0.12, 0.2, 0.25, 0.05, 0.08, 0.125, 0.175]

v = npr.choice(w, x, y, z)
```

I want to find the probability of the value V being a selection of variables eg; False or 0.12.

How do I do this. 
Heres what I've tried;

```
 import numpy.random as npr
import math 

w = [0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.13, 0.17]
x = 1
y = False
z = [0.12, 0.2, 0.25, 0.05, 0.08, 0.125, 0.175]

v = npr.choice(w, x, y, z)

from collections import Counter 
c = Counter(0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.13, 0.17,1,False,0.12, 0.2, 0.25, 0.05, 0.08, 0.125, 0.175)

def probability(0.12):
    return float(c[v]/len(w,x,y,z))
```

which I'm getting that 0.12 is an invalid syntax

Comment: You would have to pass a variable name, not a value. So, instead of `def probability(0.12)` you would have to pass `def probability(some_variable_name)` which can also be `def probability(some_variable_name=0.12)`.

Comment: In addition, `len(w, x, y, z)` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the code, I think you want the following:

```
import numpy.random as npr
import math
from collections import Counter


def probability(v=0.12):
    return float(c[v]/len(combined))


w = [0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.13, 0.17]
x = [1]
y = [False]
z = [0.12, 0.2, 0.25, 0.05, 0.08, 0.125, 0.175]

combined = w + x + y + z

v = npr.choice(combined)

c = Counter(combined)

print(probability())
print(probability(v=0.05))
```

1) `def probability(0.12)` does not make sense; you will have to pass a variable which can also have a default value (above I use `0.12`)

2) `len(w, x, y, z)` does not make much sense either; you probably look for a list that combines all the elements of `w`, `x`, `y` and `z`. I put all of those in the list `combined`.

3) One would also have to put in an additional check, in case the user passes e.g. `v=12345` which is not included in `combined` (I leave this to you).

The above will print

```
0.0625
0.125
```

which gives the expected outcome.